# wordpress plugin automatically will install, when my wp theme someone install

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I made a wordpress theme and I take some advantage from advance custom field plugin. Now I wand to distribute my plugin and also wano give on wordpress plugin directory.

But there is one problem. if I want to get all feature of my theme. Than need obviously ACF Plugin.

Now I wan, if anybody install my theme. Than ACF plugin wil automaticlly.

is there ny system/way/function?  if anybody intall my theme, than acf plugin will install automaticaly.
thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the free version of ACF within a theme (or the PRO version if you are selling a premium theme). Check [this page](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/).